# How to remove or bypass a superclass method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Some background: I have an external library that uses explicit type checking instead of duck-typing in one of its methods. Something like:

```
def a_method(value)
  case value
  when Array then 'an Array'
  when Hash  then 'a Hash'
  when Foo   then 'a Foo'
  end
end
```

`Foo` is defined in the library. I would like to pass another object to this method that should be treated like a `Foo`. Therefore, I'm subclassing `Foo`:

```
class Bar < Foo
end
```

which works just fine:

```
bar = Bar.new
a_method(bar)
#=> 'a Foo'
```

Unfortunately, `Foo` implements several `methods` that will break the way `Bar` is supposed to work, including `method_missing` and `respond_to?`. For example:

```
class Foo
  def respond_to?(method_name)
    false
  end
end
```

Because `Foo` is `Bar`'s superclass, `Foo#respond_to?` is invoked when calling `Bar#respond_to?`:

```
class Bar < Foo
  def hello
  end
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.respond_to?(:hello)  #=> false
bar.method(:respond_to?) #=> #<Method: Bar(Foo)#respond_to?>
```

I would like to remove or bypass `Foo`'s method in this case (i.e. from within `Bar`) so that:

```
bar.respond_to?(:hello)  #=> true
bar.method(:respond_to?) #=> #<Method: Bar(Kernel)#respond_to?>
```

just as if `Foo#respond_to?` did not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since Ruby lets you redefine the methods used to check things, it might be possible to make Bar lie about what it is rather than making it a real subclass.  Similar to my hash-replacement which has `def kind_of? klass; klass == Hash || super; end`, tho that doesn't work for `case` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had this class structure:

```
class A
  def respond_to?(meth)
    "A"
  end
  def cat
  end
  def tap
    puts "tap in A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def respond_to?(meth)
    "B"
  end
end

class C < B
  def respond_to?(meth)
    "C"
  end
end

class D < C
end
```

We have:

```
D.ancestors
  #=> [D, C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Further, you want:

```
D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> true
```

If we write:

```
class D < C
  def respond_to?(meth)
    method(__method__).super_method.call(meth)  
  end
end
```

then:

```
D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> C
```

This is not surprising, since it's the same as:

```
class D < C
  def respond_to?(meth)
    super
  end
end

D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> C
```

Now try:

```
class D < C
  def respond_to?(meth)
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.call(meth)  
  end
end
```

then:

```
D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> B
```

so we have skipped over `C`. Now redefine `D#respond_to?` as follows:

```
class D < C
  def respond_to?(meth)
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.super_method.call(meth)   
  end
end

D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> A
```

Once more:

```
class D < C
  def respond_to?(meth)
    method(__method__).super_method.super_method.super_method.super_method.call(meth)   
  end
end

D.new.respond_to?(:cat)
  #=> True (invokes Kernel#respond_to?)
```

Therefore, you could do the following:

```
module JumpOver
  def jump_over(over_mod, meth)
    m = instance_method(meth)
    loop do 
      m = m.super_method
      break if m.owner > over_mod
    end
    define_method(meth, m)
  end
end

class D
  extend JumpOver
  jump_over(A, :respond_to?)
  jump_over(A, :tap)
end

D.methods.include?(:jump)
  #=> true
D.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:respond_to?, :tap]    

d = D.new
  #=> #<D:0x007ff263161b58>
d.respond_to? :cat
  #=> true
d.respond_to? :dog
  #=> false
d.tap { |o| puts 'hi' }
  # 'hi'
  #=> #<D:0x007ff263161b58>
```

Comment: @Stefan, until I saw your solution I didn't realize that `define_method` could take an unbounded method as its second argument. That's great. I need to now examine how my approach differs from yours. I specify the method and module `m1` to jump over so that you have the choice of jumping or not when there is a module `m2`, `m1 < m2`, that has the method. Readers: [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method) was introduced in v2.2. Great question!

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's [method lookup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup) seems to be "hard-coded". I couldn't find a way to alter it from within Ruby.

Based on Sergio Tulentsev's suggestion to re-implement the methods, however, I came up with a helper method to replace / overwrite every superclass (instance) method with its "super" method (or undefine it if there is none):

```
def self.revert_superclass_methods
  superclass.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
    super_method = instance_method(method).super_method
    if super_method
      puts "reverting #{self}##{method} to #{super_method}"
      define_method(method, super_method)
    else
      puts "undefining #{self}##{method}"
      undef_method(method)
    end
  end
end
```

This has basically the same effect for my purposes. Example usage:

```
module M
  def foo ; 'M#foo' ; end
end

class A
  include M
  def to_s ; 'A#to_s' ; end
  def foo  ; 'A#foo'  ; end
  def bar  ; 'A#bar'  ; end
end

class B < A
  def self.revert_superclass_methods
    # ...
  end
end

b = B.new
b.to_s #=> "A#to_s"
b.foo  #=> "A#foo"
b.bar  #=> "A#bar"

B.revert_superclass_methods
# reverting B#to_s to #<UnboundMethod: Object(Kernel)#to_s>
# reverting B#foo to #<UnboundMethod: Object(M)#foo>
# undefining B#bar

b.to_s #=> "#<B:0x007fb389987490>"
b.foo  #=> "M#foo"
b.bar  #=> undefined method `bar' for #<B:0x007fb389987490> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the problem. Just implement a `respond_to?` in `Bar` and don't call `super`.

```
class Foo
  def respond_to?(method)
    puts 'in foo'
    false
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def respond_to?(method)
    puts 'in bar'
    true
  end
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.respond_to?(:quux) # => true
# >> in bar
```

This is, of course, a violation of LSP, but you specifically asked for it, so... :)

Comment: That could solve the problem, but how can I call the original / former implementation (e.g. `Kernel#respond_to?`)? I don't want to re-implement these methods.

Comment: @Stefan: another option is to patch `Foo`, so that it doesn't do such things. BTW, is this a practical question (with a real-world existing `Foo`) or just a made-up interview-kind problem? :)

Comment: It is a real problem ;-) The library is a testing framework and for specific tests, I'd like to use one of my own classes instead of the Library's built-in one. Subclassing essentially works, but implementing my replacement class would be *much* easier if I could remove / bypass / hide all of the superclass methods. Patching `Foo` or that `case` method would certainly work, but I'd prefer to leave the framework and its classes unchanged.

Comment: @Stefan: as I see it, you'll have to patch _something_. Either that `case` (so that duck-typing works and you can use composition instead of inheritance) or copy Kernel's `respond_to?`.

Comment: By "copy Kernel's `respond_to?`", I presume that would be `class Bar < Foo; define_method(:respond_to?, Kernel.instance_method(respond_to?)); end; end`. Correct?

Comment: I typically use alias_method to "rename" the original method, then define the replacement method